# Strange trim function behavior

Tags: string, postgresql, trim, postgresql-9.2

I wonder why I've got empty string as a result when I'm especting something completely else...
I use trim function to cut phone number from string:

```
select trim(leading  '509960405' from '509960405509960404');
```

Why the result isn't 509960404 as expected?

Comment: Try using `ltrim`.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: @Robert- it's nothing...

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ltrim wouldn't help because it also takes a list of characters, not a string.

Comment: @Borys I tried the query in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11582) and it got 5099604 but missed the 05 after that, but it did return.

Comment: That's already solved, thx Robert I use replace now and I'm doing replace('509960405509960404','509960405','') and it works just fine. Now i'm trying find out why that happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim` strips out any characters matching a list of characters.  All the characters in your string are in your "leading" list of characters.  What you wrote could just as easily be written as

`select trim(leading  '04569' from '509960405509960404');`

It removes any 0, 4, 5, 6 or 9 characters from the beginning of your string.  Since your string consists of only 0, 4, 5, 6, or 9 characters, it removes them all.

Comment: so why when I'm doing that select trim(both  '55' from '509960405509960404'); the result is: 09960405509960404 ?

Comment: Because it removes the 5 from the beginning.  You only have one unique character in your character list in that case, a '5', and there is only one '5' at the beginning of the string.  You should really try reading the documentation for a function before complaining that it's not working right.

Comment: I red documentation and i'm still not sure why it cut number from inside although it doesn't match.

Comment: Because as I said in the answer, it's removing all the characters that match, and they all match.

Comment: ok, thx my confusion was caused by the lack of distinction between set of characters and string as a whole, so thx ;)

Answer (score 2):

[@Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304988/939860) clarified the behaviour of `trim()`.
The *solution* you presented in the comment is potentially *treacherous*:

```
SELECT replace('509960405509960404','509960405','')
```

Replaces *all* occurrences of `'509960405'` not just the first. For example:

```
SELECT replace('509960405509960404','50996040' ,'');
```

Results in `54`. I suspect that's **not** what you want.
Use a [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) with [**`regexp_replace()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('509960405509960404','^509960405' ,'');
```

`^` .. glues the pattern to the start of the string ("left-anchored").
`regexp_replace()` is more expensive than a simple `replace()` but also more versatile.

Comment: thx, Erwin. Replace is exactly what I need in this case. My job is to find and cut all occurrences of phone numbers in many strings (yes, strings ;) because data i'm about to clean are one big mess. So if somebody puts one number many times in one field I have to return only one number and copy that somewhere else. The probability that whole and right number (with appropriate prefix) gonnna be part of another number in the same string is extremely low so I think it's good way to do that.